# Application Error during deployment to an Azure Function Slot

Tags: python, deployment, azure-functions, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

When I'm trying to deploy a code to Azure function slot in portal, the message appears in terminal VSCode

> Error: :( Application ErrorIf you are the application administrator, you can access the <a style="color: grey"href="https://name_funcion-name_slot.scm.azurewebsites.net/detectors">diagnostic resources.

When i check the deployment logs this error appears:

> {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."}}],"Innererror":null}

I would like to understand where I should have permission to deploy in the slot, because I can deploy normally in production slot. Idk, maybe some error with runtime?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you able to deploy in production slot and its working perfectly fine?? And you want to deploy to different slot??

Comment: Exactly. I try to set '1' to WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE in configuration and i select the option 'Deployment slot setting' to some configurations, but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

I created simple Http trigger and deployed to Azure function using `Consumption` plan.

This is how i deployed my function in new slot. This worked for me.

**#My Code :**

`productionslot`:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully in Production slot")
```

`newslot`:

```py
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully in a new slot")
```

Add slot in `Deployment slots`:

- Enable deployment slots.
- Provide new name to slot.
- click add
  [image]

[image]

To deploy to new slot from Vs Code:

- select  the new slot from the function.
  [image]

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

`New Slot`:

[image]

[image]